# Discord JS - forEach looped embed

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm quite new to Javascript, normally a Python person. I've looked at some other answers but my embed does not add the fields as expected. The embed itself is sent.

My Discord bot follows the guide provided by the devs (primary file, slash commands, command files). I am trying to loop through the entries in an SQLite query and add them as fields.

My command file is below.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose();

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('rank')
        .setDescription('Rank all points.'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const rankEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Rank Board')
        let db = new sqlite.Database('./databases/ranktest.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE);
        let queryall = 'SELECT name, points FROM pointstable ORDER BY points DESC'
        db.all(queryall, [], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('There was an error');
            } else {
                rows.forEach((row) => {
                    console.log(row.name, row.points)
                    rankEmbed.addField('\u200b', `${row.name}: ${row.points}`, true);
                });
            }
        })
    return interaction.reply({embeds: [ rankEmbed ] });
    }
}
```

I would also like to convert `row.name` - held as Discord IDs - to usernames i.e. `MYNAME#0001`. How do I do this by interaction? I was able to obtain the User ID in another command by using `interaction.member.id`, but in this case I need to grab them from the guild. In Python I did this with `await client.fetch_user` but in this case the error  `await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules` is thrown.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've solved the first aspect, I had the `return interaction.reply` in the wrong place.

Relevant snippet:

```
rows.forEach((row) => {
    console.log(row.name, row.points)
    rankEmbed.addField('\u200b', `${row.name}: ${row.points}`, false);
})
return interaction.reply({embeds: [rankEmbed ]} );
```

<strike>Would still appreciate an answer to the converting `row.name` (user ID) to user name via `fetch`.</strike>

I've solved the second aspect also. Add the below into the loop.

```
rows.forEach((row) => {
    let client = interaction.client
    const uname = client.users.cache.get(row.name);
    rankEmbed.addField('\u200b', `${uname}: ${row.points}`, false);
```